# Planes and their intersections

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose we know that when the three planes $P1$, $P2$ and $P3$ in space intersect in pairs,
we get three lines $L1$, $L2$, and $L3$ which are distinct and parallel.
Show that the three normals to P1, P2 and P3 all lie in one plane, using a geometric
argument.
How would one prove this with geometric argument? I sketched it, but I can only seem to prove it algebraically.

Answer (score 0):

The normals must be perpendicular to lines on the plane, hence they lie on the common orthogonal complement to $L_i$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $\pi_1\cap\pi_2=l_3$, $\pi_1\cap\pi_3=l_2$ and $\pi_2\cap\pi_3=l_1$.

Also, let $n_1$ be a normal to $\pi_1$ and let $n_1\cap\pi_1=\{N_1\}$.

Now, let $K\in n_1$ and $n_2$ be a normal to $\pi_2$ such that $K\in n_2$.

Let $n_2\cap\pi_2=\{N_2\}$, $(KN_1N_2)\cap l_3=\{C\},$ $CN_1\cap l_2=\{B\}$ and $CN_2\cap l_1=\{A\}$.

Thus, $(ABC)\perp\pi_3$.

Now, let $CD$ be an altitude of $\Delta ABC.$

Thus, $CD$ is a normal to $\pi_3$ and we see that any normal to our planes they are parallel to the plane $(ABC).$

Answer (score 0):

The direction vector of the line $L_3 = P_1 \cap P_2$ is orthogonal to the plane normals $n_1$ and $n_2$.

The direction vector of the line $L_1 = P_2 \cap P_3$ is orthogonal to the plane normals $n_2$ and $n_3$.

Since $L_3$ and $L_1$ are parallel $\{ n_1, n_3\}$ and $\{ n_2, n_3 \}$ span the same plane.